# Normalization of the partition function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, partition-function

I am used to think that multiplying the partition function by a constant is meaningless, and shouldn't change any calculation, as under $Z' = A Z = A \sum_n \exp(-\beta E_n)$ for an arbitrary $A$, the factor will cancel for all observables
$$ O = \frac{1}{Z}\sum_n o_n e^{-\beta E_n} = \frac{1}{AZ}\sum_n A o_n e^{-\beta E_n} $$
and the generalization for continuous system, or the quantum mechanical version, is quite straight-forward. And specifically, as $p_n = \exp(-\beta E_n)/Z$ then a constant multiplying the denominator and the numerator will not affect anything.

However, if I look at $\beta F = \ln(Z)$ I get that $$F' = T\ln(AZ) = T\ln A + F$$ which means that I should interpret the multiplication of $A$ as contributing to the entropy? Are there any assumptions going into the expression $F=T \ln Z$ that I missed?

Comment: But the zero points of free energy/entropy also don't effect any observables.

Comment: @jacob1729 I think where one may have doubt is that in quantum case entropy should go to zero at zero temperature.

Comment: @jacob1729 but isn't entropy quite well defined as the log of the number of micro-states? as Roger Vadim says - at T->0 we would want S to go to a number that reflects gs degeneracy

Comment: @yyy in classical stat. mech. the entropy is defined only up to a constant - since there is some ambiguity about how one counts the states for continuous variables.